# Invalid pointer after a call to delete

Tags: c++, invalid-pointer

I have this simple code in a file called `virtual.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>


class Parent
{
    public:
    virtual ~Parent(){ std::cout << "Parent Destructor" << std::endl; }

    virtual void VirtualFunction()
    {
        std::cout << "VirtualFunctionInParent" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Child: public Parent
{
    public:
    virtual ~Child() { std::cout << "Child Destructor" << std::endl; }
    virtual void VirtualFunction()
    {
        std::cout << "VirtualFunctionInChild" << std::endl;
    }    
};

int main()
{
    Child child1;
    Parent *parent1 = &child1;
    delete parent1;

}
```

It compiles correctly

```
g++ -Wall --pedantic -o virtual virtual.cpp
```

But when I run it, I obtain this error:

```
./virtual 
Child Destructor
Parent Destructor
free(): invalid pointer
Annullato (core dump creato)
```

I think it is due to the fact that I delete the pointer parent1, so this erases the memory to which the pointer point, namely `&child1`.
So, when child1 goes out of scope, the Child destructor try to deallocate memory which no longer exists.

***My questions:***

1. is my reasoning correct?
2. if my reasoning is correct, which is the correct way to handle this "going out of scope" situation?

Comment: Only `delete` what you `new`.

Comment: @DrewDormann Thanks. What if the main was `Child child1; Parent *parent1 = new Parent; parent1 = &child1; delete parent1`

Comment: You'd have the same problem PLUS a memory leak because the `new Parent;`'s address was overwritten and lost.

Comment: @vaeVictis now that you have gotten several answers, I do not recommend using this space to ask new questions.  There is an [ Ask Question ] button if you need it.

Comment: @vaeVictis *so this erases the memory* -- That phrase right there indicates you are not aware of what the purpose of `delete` is.

Comment: I wonder if `delete` should be replaced by `un_new`.

Comment: @vaeVictis -- The keyword `delete` doesn't mean "erase".  It's purpose is to inform the allocator that a previously allocated memory that was allocated using `new` is now available to be reused (if necessary).  Nothing actually gets "erased".   What *may* happen is that the debug runtime will write over the area with a value, but that's the extent of the "erasure".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks. As I answered to Drew Dormann, I do not manage properly the terminology. I wrote "erases" meaning "frees" (or "releases"). Thank you.

Comment: You're going to find that it is very hard to discuss programing with programmers without knowing and using the correct terminology.

Comment: C++ has different kinds of memory storage:  automatic, dynamic, thread, and static.  You have an object in automatic storage, but then you try to `delete` the object as if it were in dynamic storage.  Cue the Yakety Sax music and chase scene.  q.v. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I delete the pointer parent1, so this erases the memory to which the pointer point.  Is my reasoning correct?

No.  You are getting a core dump **from** your delete.

Only addresses returned from `new` may be passed to `delete`.

`delete` does not **erase** memory, as memory has no concept of an "erased" state.

> which is the correct way to handle this "going out of scope" situation?

Remove the `delete` line.  It is not necessary.

Any variable created within a scope is automatically managed when that scope is left.

Comment: I do not properly manage the terminology, thanks for pointing out. I meant that delete freed the memory pointed by parent1. Is it correct?

Comment: @vaeVictis `delete` will call the destructor(s) of the object(s) pointed to, and then free or _release_ the memory.  Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `delete` on an object you didn't allocate with `new`. This object will be deleted when it goes out of scope, so there's nothing special to do to destroy it properly.

When you want objects to start their lifetime inside a scope and end their lifetime when the scope ends, don't use `new` and `delete`. Just declare them normally.

Use `new` and `delete` for objects whose lifetimes you want to manage. Allocate them with `new` and call `delete` when you are done with them.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is the fact that you don't use `new` or any other way to allocate the **dynamic** memory. So there is no point to use `delete`.

To answer your next questions you must first tell us  why do you want to create the parent pointer on address of the child?

Comment: I am just working with virtual function, the usual call to `parent1->VirtualFunction()` and dynamic binding (hope I used the proper terminology). The rest of the code is not present, since it was not part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question more specifically

1. is my reasoning correct?

You are never going out of scope because you are declaring variables to the current stack frame in main().  In order to declare the variable to the heap (out of scope), you have to use dynamic memory allocation.

```
Parent * parent1 = new(Child);
delete(parent1);
```

What this code is doing is creating a child class in heap and then creating a parent1 pointer local to the scope that effectively points to the child class.